# sql server logical reads are more with where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT C.custid, C.companyname,
O.orderid, O.orderdate
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS O
ON C.custid = O.custid

(830 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Customers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.


SELECT C.custid, C.companyname,
O.orderid, O.orderdate
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS O
ON C.custid = O.custid
WHERE O.custid < 5

(30 row(s) affected)
Table 'Customers'. Scan count 0, logical reads 60, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

In second query I'm limiting the rows with `O.custid < 5` still it gives me logical reads 60? It should be less than 21 which shown for first query in customer table.

Comment: Logical reads don't mean a lot. Measure elapsed time. A where clause can mean both less or more work for SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the query plans for the two queries. SQL Server has several options for performing these queries. For instance, here are some examples:

- Scanning `Customers` and looking up each order in `Orders` using an index.
- Scanning `Orders` table and looking up each customer in `Customers`.
- Creating a hash table for `Orders` and `Customers` and then merging the results in the hash table.
- Sorting both `Customers` and `Orders` and doing a merge join.

(and there are undoubtedly other possibilities as well).

In any case, the SQL optimizer chooses the best method for doing the `join`. When you add a `where` clause, the best solution may be different. This is expected, and an indication that the optimizer is doing its job.